# OneNote local backup

Tags: backup, power-automate, onenote

I am looking for an automation with Microsoft Power Automate or other tool, which automatically creates a local backup of a OneNote Notebook or of the Onedrive folder in which the OneNote notebook is inside in a certain interval.

Answer (score 0):

Onenote 2016 ("old" onenote which comes with office 365 but is also available for free) has a built in backuptool which can make a local backup every X hours/days.

You only have to make sure Onenote is always open.